# Working with matrices in r

Tags: r, matrix

I'm working on code to construct an option pricing matrix. What I have at the moment is the values along the diagonal part of the matrix. Currently I'm working in a matrix with 4 rows and 4 columns. What I'm attempting to do is to use the values in the diagonal part of the matrix to give values in the lower triangle of the matrix. So for my matrix `Omat`, `Omat[1,1]+Omat[2,2]` will give a value for `[2,1]`, `Omat[2,2]+Omat[3,3]` will give a value for `[3,2]`. Then using these created values, `Omat[2,1]+Omat[3,2]` will give a value for `[3,1]`.

My attempt:

```
Omat = diag(2, 4, 4)
Omat[j+i,j] <- Omat[i-1,j]+Omat[i,j+1]
```

Any ideas on how one could go about this?

What I currently have, a 4 row by 4 col matrix:

```
Omat
# 2   0   0   0
# 0   2   0   0
# 0   0   2   0
# 0   0   0   2
```

What I've been attempting to create, a 4 row by 4 col matrix:

```
 0 0 0 0
 4 0 0 0
 8 4 0 0
16 8 4 0
```

Comment: Based on your description, it seems like 2/3 or more of the code you provide isn't relevant. Maybe just show a simple matrix and ask how to do that last operation? Things become very clear when simplified to input and desired output of the one step that's giving you trouble.

Comment: I trimmed down what seemed like extra stuff. I think it's nice and clear now, but rollback or edit back in anything important I got rid of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try calculating successive diagonals underneath the main diagonal.  Code could look like:

```
Omat = diag(2,4)
for(i in 1:(nrow(Omat)-1)) {
  for( j in (i+1):nrow(Omat)) {
    Omat[j,j-i] <- Omat[j,j-i+1] + Omat[j-1,j-i]
  }
}
diag(Omat) <- 0
```

Comment: Hi Walt,
Thanks for your help! I think i'm very close to adapting it to my code.

Comment: @Joe McGrath  Thanks for the feedback.  If this solution works for you, you might tick the accept box so other SO users will recognize it as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Am I probably missing something, but why not do this:

```
for (i in 2:dim){
    for (j in 1:(i-1)){
        Omat[i,j] <- Omat[i-1,j] + Omat[i,j+1]
    }
}
diag(Omat) <- 0
```

,David.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the reply. But the problem there is i need the values that are created to be the new values. As in the code you provided gives me the values using the diag of the matrix, but i'm looking to loop back over those created figures. so Omat[2,1]+Omat[3,2] will give a value for [3,1].